# Uniqueness of horizontal lifts

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

Consider a fibre bundle $E$ and a certain connection, $TE=H\oplus V$. A path $\gamma(t)\in B$ can be horizontally lifted to a path $\gamma(t)\in E$ according to $\pi\circ\tilde\gamma=\gamma$ and $\tilde\gamma'\in H$. Apparently, this lift is unique.

I seem to be having a bit of a mental block. Why is this lift unique? Consider e.g. a trivial bundle $E=B\times F$, with connection $H=TB\times\{0\}$. Then for any $f\in F$, the lift $\tilde\gamma(t):=(\gamma(t),f)$ is a horizontal lift of $\gamma(t)\in B$, right? So how is this unique? If any $f$ defines an horizontal lift, it most certainly is not unique. What gives?

Comment: In case my notation is unclear: letting $\pi'$ be the projection into $F$, the horizontal space is defined as the kernel of $\pi'$.

Comment: Unique up to the lift of the initial point $\gamma(0)$ (or any other point on the path).

Comment: @s.harp Hmm by $\gamma(0)$ you actually mean $\tilde\gamma(0)$, right? because $\gamma(0)$ is independent of $f$, or am I missing something?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransofrm here this is grammar, when I say "lift of the initial point $\gamma(0)$" I mean "choice of $\tilde\gamma(0)$", as that would be a lift of $\gamma(0)$ :)

Comment: @s.harp Ugh, sorry for being dense. I need some more coffee...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one wants to lift a homotopy $f:X\times [0,1]\to B$ to the total space, part of the data *always* is a lift $\tilde f_0: X\times \{0\}\to E$ so that $\pi\circ \tilde f_0= f_0$. With this in mind it may be clear why when one says a lift is unique, one means unique up to the choice of this initial "lift at zero".

Specifically the theorem should be reformulated here as: For any point $f$ in the fibre of $\pi^{-1}(\gamma(0))$ there is a unique horizontal lift $\tilde\gamma$ of $\gamma$ so that $\tilde\gamma(0)=f$ and $\pi\circ\tilde\gamma = \gamma$.